# RabbitMQ Error while pushing a message to queue

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am trying to push a JSON message to the RabbitMQ queue using a message exchange. I have installed RabbitMQ through a docker.

I have create and started a docker container using the following:

```
docker run -d --hostname myrabbit --name rabbit-assignment -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=/ -p 15672:15672
rabbitmq:3-management
```

Below is my application.properties

```
spring.rabbitmq.port = 15672
spring.rabbitmq.username = guest
spring.rabbitmq.password = guest
server.port = 9292
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=/
```

Below is the error:

```
2022-01-15 16:35:52.828 ERROR 44873 --- [nio-9292-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException] with root cause

java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91) ~[amqp-client-5.13.1.jar:5.13.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:184) ~[amqp-client-5.13.1.jar:5.13.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:665) ~[amqp-client-5.13.1.jar:5.13.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

Answer (score 1):

spring.rabbitmq.port = 15672
you're using 15672 as the port. This is only the UI/admin port.
The port for applications to use is 5672.

Just change that and you'll be running along.

BR,
~A